# How to swipe RecyclerView Item when I click Button..?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have multiple items in recyclerView and each item has one cross button. I want to remove that item when I click on Cross button. I am able to swipe that item but want to implement it on Button Click.

My Adapter Is

```
public class RecyclerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

private static final String[] STRINGS = new String[]{
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"
};

private final List<String> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback;


public RecyclerListAdapter(Activity activity, ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback) {
    mItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(STRINGS));
    this.context = activity;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(mItems.get(position));
    holder.ivCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Swipe item from here
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(mItems, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(mItems, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

My CallBack is

```
public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;

public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}
```

My Activity is

```
public class MainFragment extends Activity {

public ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Activity activity = MainFragment.this;
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));


    RecyclerListAdapter adapter = new RecyclerListAdapter(activity,callback);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);


    ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


}
```

Please guide me..

Comment: Update Your RecyclerView Adapter with my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Set for Cross button an onClickListener in the adapter onBindViewHolder method, and in that remove the item from your array (with help of position parameter) and call notifyDatasetChanged or you can call your swipe method there.